# Зачем нужны расширения PHP на PECL?

Tags: php, memcached, pecl, memcache

В PHP есть расширения например php-apc и php-memcache. Их можно поставить из обычного репозитория или из PEAR/PECL . В чём смысл использования PEAR / PECL ?? насколько memcache из pecl стабильнее и насколько потребляет меньше ресурсов?? (актуально для ububntu 12.04 14.04 и PHP 5.3 и 5.5)

Answer (score 1):

Что вы называете *"обычным репозиторием"*: репозиторий пакетов операционки или репозиторий с исходниками конкретных библиотек (github, google code и т.п.)?

Менеджеры пакетов deb/yum ставят те же pecl-расширения. Разница в том, что менеджер пакетов будет поддерживать непротиворечивость версий при апгрейдах, а за тем, что вы качнули и собрали самостоятельно, вам придется следить также самостоятельно.

PEAR можно считать умер, лучше из него ничего не ставить.

Comment: https://toster.ru/q/208534?e=1834345#comment_709213 обсуждение на тостере